# Azure hosted Wordpress site taking long to connect to domain

Tags: wordpress, azure, web-config

I'm running a wordpress website on Azure with a MySQL DB both located in East US

However, for some reason recently the website has been taking a much longer time than usual to connect. The first request to connect to the domain takes 6+ seconds.

I've edited the Web config file and worked with a Cache for the website but its still giving me the long waiting times. Would Appreciate any help. 
[longwaitingtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1P22.png)